# how to create XML file from database in vb.net

Tags: sql, xml, vb.net

how to create XML file from database using vb.net
As i tried i just got only the root elements created and not any data's from the database and my code is:

```
<% @Import Namespace="System" %>
<% @Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<% @Import Namespace="System.xml" %>
<% @Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>

<Script runat="server">
Sub Page_Load

Dim connectionString As String
Dim connection As SqlConnection
Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
Dim ds  As New DataSet
Dim sql As String

connectionString =// my connection string///
connection = New SqlConnection(connectionString) 


sql = "select * from jb_jobs where city='Los Angeles' "
connection.Open()
adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)
adapter.Fill(ds)
connection.Close()
If IO.File.Exists("product.xml") = False Then
Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings()
settings.Indent = True
Dim XmlWrt As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("c:/xmlfiles/product.xml", settings)
XmlWrt.WriteStartDocument()
XmlWrt.WriteComment("XML Database.")
XmlWrt.WriteStartElement("source")
XmlWrt.WriteStartElement("jobs")



XmlWrt.WriteEndElement()
XmlWrt.WriteEndDocument()
XmlWrt.Close()
End If
End Sub
</script>
```

and i got the output is just an XML file is created with only the root elements described above and not the data's from database.

How to get data's from database and form the XML file?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the WriteXml method, something like this:

```
Private Sub WriteXmlToFile(thisDataSet As DataSet)
 If thisDataSet Is Nothing Then 
     Return 
 End If  

' Create a file name to write to. 
 Dim filename As String = "XmlDoc.xml" 

 ' Create the FileStream to write with. 
 Dim stream As New System.IO.FileStream _
    (filename, System.IO.FileMode.Create)

 ' Write to the file with the WriteXml method.
 thisDataSet.WriteXml(stream)
End Sub
```

You can find out more about the [DataTable.WriteXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) and [DataSet.WriteXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa57x5f2.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: I'm not having any problem in creating the XML file but the problem is in retrieving values from database and saving it to the XML file

Answer (score 0):

So you should have asked about '*retrieving data from the database*'??

How about changing the SQL statement:

SQL = `select * from jb_jobs where city='Los Angeles'`

to

SQL = `select * from jb_jobs where city LIKE 'Los Angeles'` -> String

or

SQL = `select * from jb_jobs where city = CityID` -> Integer